# 2 AJAX commands that work, but I only see the last "responseText"

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have two JS functions that preforms AJAX calls, I've wanted to test them so I've created two paragraphs with different ids that will hold the result of the responses text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      

    trackApplicationAdded('1139631160', '12445'); //should change test1 paragraph
    trackApplicationRemoved('1139631160'); //should change test2 paragraph

</script> 

<p>Test1: <span id="test1"></span></p>
<p>Test2: <span id="test2"></span></p>
```

When I run each function on its own (`commenting` on of them), each one changes its own paragraph as expected, but when I run both of them, I can only see the paragraph change made by the **LAST** function.

I have a function that creates an XMLHttpRequest that gets the variable `test` which send the paragraph id that should be changed by each function (and as noted, it is working when each one is called by itself).

```
function sendRequest(url, params, test)
{

 // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
    httpRequest=new XMLHttpRequest();
}     
else // code for IE6, IE5
{
    httpRequest=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

httpRequest.open("POST", url, true); 

//Set request headers for POST command//
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

 httpRequest.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
    if(httpRequest.readyState==4 && httpRequest.status==200)
    {
        //Here you can see "test" which, depends on the function, is test1 or test2//
        document.getElementById(test).innerHTML=httpRequest.responseText;
    }
 }

httpRequest.send(params);

//end when the server will responde we will execute the "document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;" //
```

}

By the way, the AJAX preforms database `insert` by PHP functions and its everything working good in any situation. It is important to note that the problem is only with the paragraph changes and not what happens in the server.

Any one have an idea how to solve this ? Thanks...

**EDIT**

Here is the code of the 2 functions:

```
function trackApplicationAdded(fID, fappID) 
{    

var url = "trackApplicationAdded.php";
var params = "facebookID=" + fID + "&facebookApplicationID=" +fappID;

sendRequest(url,params, "test1");  
}


function trackApplicationRemoved(fID) 
{    

var url = "trackApplicationRemoved.php";
var params = "facebookID=" + fID;

sendRequest(url,params, "test2");  
}
```

Comment: Unless I missed something.. you are setting the innerHTML in both ajax calls, and the problem is that you want both results to show? Why don't you just concatenate the innerHTML instead?

Comment: You should post that code that sets up the "httpRequest" variable - *exactly* the code you use, because I've got a hunch as to what the problem is.

Comment: You need to post the code inside `trackApplicationAdded` and `trackApplicationRemoved`.

Comment: @jbabey both ajax calls are being called from the same function (`sendRequest`), each time with different variable that should write the `innerHTML` to a different parahgraph.

Comment: If you don't post that code, you're probably not going to get the help you need.  The part commented out in "sendRequest()" is probably where the problem is.

Comment: Let me just ask this:  in "sendRequest()", is the "httpRequest" variable declared with `var` or not?

Comment: @Pointy it declared without `var`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `var` when you declared "httpRequest", so the second call overwrites the first. Without the `var` declaration the variable is global.

At the top of "sendRequest()" just add:

```
var httpRequest;
```

Comment: Thanks alot! it did solve the problem. But now I don't understand how the commands in the server worked with no problems when both of the functions worked, why the global `var` only effected the returned text ? can you please explain... thanks :)

Comment: The server side worked fine because the browser did indeed issue two separate HTTP requests. It's just that your code overwrote the state change event handler from the first request, so when the browser got the response back it passed it to the handler set up for the *second* call, which only updated the second "test" `<span>` and not the first one.

Comment: I see, but shouldn't the first request go to `readyState==4` and execute the `innerHTML` command before the second request overwrote the handler ?

Comment: No, because they would both be issued by the browser almost at the same time; they're asynchronous.  The ready state doesn't change until the response comes back from the server.